# Error rust syncing channel updates 'nightly --- (error reading rustc version)'

Tags: rust

I'm having errors with autocomplete so I decided to install everything again but this having this error when doing:

```
rustup update nightly
```

> info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
>
> nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - (error reading rustc
>   version)

in rust rustc 1.17.0

Answer (score 0):

When doing:

```
->rustup override set nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
info: using existing install for 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: override toolchain for '/home/' set to 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

  nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.19.0-nightly (d3abc80b3 2017-05-09)
```

Is able to recognize now:

- `nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.19.0-nightly (d3abc80b3 2017-05-09)`

instead of

- `nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - (error reading rustc version)`

Then I do `update nightly` because maybe it was corrupt or maybe not and it is normal, and maybe it would have worked

```
->rustup update nightly
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

  nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.19.0-nightly (d3abc80b3 2017-05-09)
```

I did some tests and at first did not recognize it `rustc 1.19.0-nightly (d3abc80b3 2017-05-09)` I had to execute 2 times `->rustup update nightly`

---

According to was looking can be used `toolchain uninstall` *but this last I can not confirm*:

```
->rustup toolchain uninstall nightly
info: uninstalling toolchain 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: toolchain 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu' uninstalled

->rustup self update

//..
->rustup update nightly
//..
```

---

Note: Maybe this `(error reading rustc version)` Really is not any serious "error" and can work without recognizing the version `rustc 1.19.0-nightly (d3abc80b3 2017-05-09)`

Answer (score 0):

After `rustup update` I got:

```
  stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - (error reading rustc version)
   nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu updated - rustc 1.19.0-nightly (978d2cfee 2017-05-10)
```

After that I tried: `rustup default stable` and I get:

```
  stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.17.0 (56124baa9 2017-04-24)
```

And if I try again `rustup update` I get:

```
   stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.17.0 (56124baa9 2017-04-24)
  nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.19.0-nightly (978d2cfee 2017-05-10)
```

So it seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is easy as drinking water. Just make sure that where you install rust, keep nightly and whatever is related with it on the same file location, mine worked when i did that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).